# Can we use height in percentage in css?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am using 5 banner images with hover effects and using below code

```
#banner
{
    float:left;
    width:99.025%;
    padding:0 0 0 10px;
    margin:0;
    height: 16.714em; /* 234px*/
    position:relative;
    overflow:hidden;
    display:block;
    background:url('/pages/images/bottom_wood_repeater.jpg') 0 104px repeat-x;
}

#banner img
{
    float:left;
    width:19.435%; /*197px;*/
}

#banner a img
{
    float:left;
    display:block;
}

#banner a:hover img
{
    float:left;
    position:relative;
    top:-16.714em; /* 234px*/
}
```

Can i use height in percentage instead of em?

```
height: 16.714em; /* 234px*/
```

Actually i am creating responsive design and it is creating problem for smaller resolution or for mobile.

Current site : http://new.brandonplanning.com/home

Thanks in Advance :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes and no.

Specifically, you can *not* do that if the parent element does not have a fixed height. Think about it: if an element could have a height equal to a percentage of its parent's height, then the parent's height would need to be calculated first. But to calculate the parent's height, you need first to calculate the height of its children. But before you calculate the height of this child, you need to calculate the parent's height. You see where this is going.

If the parent *does* have a fixed height then percentage heights on children are fine.

If the parent does *not* have a fixed height and you set a percentage height to a child the browser will simply give up and treat the child as having `height: auto`.

Comment: Thanks for quick reply will try to add parent height as fixed height and try.

Thanks a lot :)

Comment: Hey Jon can you please go through my site and suggest me something to hide below blue banner which is shown on hover state. Or i have another option that i will try to use each and every banner seperately in front use main images or on hover will try to give background images? you suggest what will be the best way to do this? Again thaks :)

Answer (score 1):

> Can i use height in percentage instead of em?

Yes you can.  with `height:25%;` but probably not going to achieve what you want if other properties are being factored in.

> Height can be
>
> auto  - The browser calculates the height. This is default
>
> length    - Defines the height in px, cm, etc.
>
> % - Defines the height in percent of the containing block

If you are still having issues with the layout you can detect if the client is on mobile and present them with a different CSS.

Comment: This is misleading. You can *write* that, but it will not work unless the parent's height is fixed.

Comment: Based on the question, it is not misleading.  And I agree with your answer.

Comment: Read my answer or try it yourself. It's not rocket science.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you are adding the "%" sign to your css you can always use %.

Answer (score 0):

I cannot see why not. As technically it's OK. Did you try using %?

Comment: Yes i tried using %, Try to reduce browser size it will automatically reduce everything and make them fit according to screen but i am facing problem with banner images as you reduce the size of browser then images will reduce accordingly as i have given their width in percentage but height is in em so the below half image is also seen. Thanks :)

Comment: can you provide picture of bug?

Comment: Can you please tell how to add images in this?

Answer (score 0):

Simply put yes we use height in percentage in css.